# Search or sort multi dimensional array for closest lat and lon values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This may be difficult, I want to search the following multi-dimensional array based on closest match of lat and lon and return that sub-array.

For example I will have the following values already set:

Lat=50.6000, Lon=-74.15000

And I want to search the following, and return the array that is the closest match. Or sort the whole thing by closest to furthest.

Even better would be a way to just sort the list so the closest lat/lon are first down to the furthest away from. What I DON'T need is it sorted in descending order. I needs to be closest to the preset value above for example. Anyone have an idea?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [zipcode] => 28299
        [latitude] => 36.234982
        [longitude] => -81.913799
        [cityname] => ACME
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [zipcode] => 17198
        [latitude] => 50.735880
        [longitude] => -74.143855
        [cityname] => NEWLAND
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [zipcode] => 12203
        [latitude] => 41.711931
        [longitude] => -75.011806
        [cityname] => ACE
    )
)
```

Comment: So in the example above it would return  array [1].  Or if it could return them all it would return in order based on distance : array[1], array[2], array[0] in that order.  Hopefully I make sense.

Comment: actually what I need to do is add up the abs value of lat and long and the smallest would be the closest to mine.. I think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Function here would do just that.... however, it returns a Multidimensional Array with with 2 major Elements `latitudes` and `longitudes`. The longitudes hold all the sorted Entries for the **closest longitude** values and the "latitudes" as well hold the sorted Entries for the **closest latitude** values. By default, the Function only returns the very Closest Match latitudinally and longitudinally. However, passing false as the last Parameter returns all sorted entries. The Code below illustrates it all:

```
<?php
    $arrGeoData = array(
        array(
            "zipcode"   => 28299,
            "latitude"  => 36.234982,
            "longitude" => -81.913799,
            "cityname"  => "ACME",
        ),
        array(
            "zipcode"   => 17198,
            "latitude"  => 50.735880,
            "longitude" => -74.143855,
            "cityname"  => "NEWLAND",
        ),
        array(
            "zipcode"   => 12203,
            "latitude"  => 41.711931,
            "longitude" => -75.011806,
            "cityname"  => "ACE",
        ),
    );
    $nearestLongLat     = sortByNearestLatLong($arrGeoData, 50.6000, -74.15000);
    var_dump(nearestLongLat);

    function sortByNearestLatLong($geoData, $lat, $long, $returnNearestOnly=true){
        // CREATE AN ARRAY FOR USE INSIDE THE FUNCTION
        $arrCloseMatchLat   = array();
        $arrCloseMatchLong  = array();
        $matchedGeoSet      = array();

        // LOOP THROUGH ALL THE $geoData ARRAY AND SUBTRACT THE GIVEN LAT & LONG VALUES
        // FROM THOSE CONTAINED IN THE ORIGINAL ARRAY: $geoData
        // WE KNOW THAT THE SMALLER THE RESULT OF THE SUBTRACTION; THE CLOSER WE ARE
        // WE DO THIS FOR BOTH THE LONGITUDE & LATITUDE... HENCE OUR ARRAY:
        // $arrCloseMatchLat AND $arrCloseMatchLong RESPECTIVELY
        foreach($geoData as $iKey=>$arrGeoStrip){
            $arrCloseMatchLat[$iKey]    =  abs(floatval( ($arrGeoStrip['latitude'])  - $lat  ));
            $arrCloseMatchLong[$iKey]   =  abs(floatval( ($arrGeoStrip['longitude']) - $long ));
        }


    // WE SORT BOTH ARRAYS NUMERICALLY KEEPING THE KEYS WHICH WE NEED FOR OUR FINAL RESULT
        asort($arrCloseMatchLat, SORT_NUMERIC);
        asort($arrCloseMatchLong, SORT_NUMERIC);

        // WE CAN RETURN ONLY THE RESULT OF THE FIRST, CLOSEST MATCH
        if($returnNearestOnly){
            foreach($arrCloseMatchLat as $index=>$difference){
                $matchedGeoSet['latitudes'][]  = $geoData[$index];
                break;
            }
            foreach($arrCloseMatchLong as $index=>$difference){
                $matchedGeoSet['longitudes'][] = $geoData[$index];
                break;
            }
            // OR WE CAN RETURN THE ENTIRE $geoData ARRAY ONLY SORTED IN A "CLOSEST FIRST" FASHION...
            // WE DO THIS FOR BOTH THE LONGITUDE & LATITUDE RESPECTIVELY SO WE END UP HAVING 2
            // ARRAYS: ONE THAT SORTS THE CLOSEST IN TERMS OF LONG VALUES
            // AN ONE THAT SORTS THE CLOSEST IN TERMS OF LAT VALUES...
        }else{
            foreach($arrCloseMatchLat as $index=>$difference){
                $matchedGeoSet['latitudes'][]  = $geoData[$index];
            }
            foreach($arrCloseMatchLong as $index=>$difference){
                $matchedGeoSet['longitudes'][] = $geoData[$index];
            }
        }
        return $matchedGeoSet;
    }
```

> The lines:  **$nearestLongLat     = sortByNearestLatLong($arrGeoData, 50.6000, -74.15000);
>         var_dump(nearestLongLat);** above produces something like below. Notice the latitudes and longitudes keys

```
    array (size=2)
      'latitudes' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=4)
              'zipcode' => int 17198
              'latitude' => float 50.73588
              'longitude' => float -74.143855
              'cityname' => string 'NEWLAND' (length=7)
      'longitudes' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=4)
              'zipcode' => int 17198
              'latitude' => float 50.73588
              'longitude' => float -74.143855
              'cityname' => string 'NEWLAND' (length=7)
```

> Now, we try again with a different set of Coordinates:   
>     **$nearestLongLat     = sortByNearestLatLong($arrGeoData, 25.6000, -84.15000);
>     var_dump($nearestLongLat);**. This  produces:

```
array (size=2)
  'latitudes' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'zipcode' => int 28299
          'latitude' => float 36.234982
          'longitude' => float -81.913799
          'cityname' => string 'ACME' (length=4)
  'longitudes' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'zipcode' => int 28299
          'latitude' => float 36.234982
          'longitude' => float -81.913799
          'cityname' => string 'ACME' (length=4)
```

Comment: Shoot ,actually this isn't working ... Try with different values and it produces the same result

Comment: @MikeQ    what other values did you try?

Comment: @MikeQ   The Code is updated....the Problem was `arsort($arrCloseMatchLat, SORT_NUMERIC);` instead of `asort($arrCloseMatchLat, SORT_NUMERIC);`. Try it again

Comment: I am very glad you had responded I could not figure out the problem.. it looks like it is working thus far!!!   It is fitting into my code where I take keyword turn into zip  then need to sort by lat / lon .. thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
$cities = <your array>;

$point = array(
    'latitude' => 50.6000,
    'longitude' => -74.15000
);

function distance($a, $b) {
    return sqrt(
        pow($a['latitude'] - $b['latitude'], 2)
        + pow($a['longitude'] - $b['longitude'], 2));
}

usort($cities, function($p, $q) {
    global $point;
    return distance($p, $point) - distance($q, $point);
});
```

This uses the naive Euclidean distance formula, for more accurate calculations replace `distance` with one of the formulae listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance

Comment: Thanks for responding, I feel that should not need to use this formula if I am just comparing numbers, is that wrong to assume?

Comment: @MikeQ: if you're looking for points "close" to each other, you're comparing their distances, not coordinates. See also below.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can combine the calculation and return the full array in order a little better if I do it like this. Will need to do some testing but it looks correct so far. @poiz

```
function sort2ByNearestLatLong($geoData, $lat, $long, $returnNearestOnly=false){

    $arrCloseMatch = array();
    $matchedGeoSet = array();

    // LOOP THROUGH ALL THE $geoData ARRAY AND SUBTRACT THE GIVEN LAT & LONG VALUES
    // FROM THOSE CONTAINED IN THE ORIGINAL ARRAY: $geoData
    // WE KNOW THAT THE SMALLER THE RESULT OF THE SUBTRACTION; THE CLOSER WE ARE
    // WE DO THIS FOR BOTH THE LONGITUDE & LATITUDE... HENCE OUR ARRAY 
    // $arrClostMatch and add the values calculated for Lat/Lon:
    foreach($geoData as $iKey=>$arrGeoStrip){
        $arrCloseMatch[$iKey] = abs(floatval( ($arrGeoStrip['latitude'])  - $lat )) + abs(floatval( ($arrGeoStrip['longitude']) - $long ));
    }

    // SORT ARRAY NUMERICALLY KEEPING THE KEYS WHICH WE NEED FOR OUR FINAL RESULT
    asort($arrCloseMatch, SORT_NUMERIC);

    // RETURN CLOSEST OR FULL LIST
    foreach($arrCloseMatch as $index=>$difference){

            $matchedGeoSet['latitudes'][]  = $geoData[$index];
            if ($returnNearestOnly==true) {
                    break;
            }
   }

   return $matchedGeoSet;
}
```

Comment: @Poiz this is a rework of what you posted..  thoughts?

Comment: This formula doesn't look correct, e.g.  it says that the distances between `(0,0)` and `(0,4)` and between `(0,0)` and `(2,2)` are the same, which is not the case.

Comment: @georg    GREAT QUESTION.  I agree however,  Thought experiment - My results return  5 chicago towns then something further away so those 5 towns will always be very similar in numbers so it always works. The other results will be much farther off and hence fail.  So it seems to be working ...  I will test some more and let you know :-)