# Sort Array with Geographical Coordinates by Shortest Route (Traveling Salesman)

Tags: php, traveling-salesman

I want to sort an array by the shortest possible route, as described in the Traveling Salesman Problem.

"Given a set of cities and distance between every pair of cities, the problem is to find the shortest possible route that visits every city exactly once and returns to the starting point"*

```
$start = [51.00, 9.00];
$places = [
  [51.31, 9.49],
  [52.51, 9.89],
  [51.81, 12.49],
  // ...
];
```

Can this library https://github.com/letournel/path-finder help to solve this problem and if so, how?

*) thanks to @Patrick Q for helping clarify this question: [Sort Array with Geographical Coordinates by Shortest Route (Traveling Salesman)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692063/sort-array-with-geographical-coordinates-by-shortest-route-traveling-salesman#comment86479718_49692063)

Comment: Maybe you can have simpler approach using https://github.com/mjaschen/phpgeo/blob/master/README.md. Then your determine the distance between your start point and all other locations and finally sorts them by distance. You repeat that for each step. However It's not an optimized method for a large dataset.

Comment: To start with, you need to determine exactly what it is you're wanting to solve.  You've put three different problem/algorithm names in here, all of which mean something slightly different.

Comment: Please see following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536014/search-or-sort-multi-dimensional-array-for-closest-lat-and-lon-values

Comment: @UgoT. sorting by distance is my current approach, unfortunately it doesn't take the direction (North, South, East, West) into account. In this regard, the matrix in the path-finder lib makes sense.

Comment: @PatrickQ - I tried to clearify my question. Thank you.

Comment: @marcus This is the definition of the Travelling Salesman Problem: "Given a set of cities and distance between every pair of cities, the problem is to find the shortest possible route that visits every city exactly once _and returns to the starting point_" (emphasis mine). Please not that this is _not_ necessarily the same as "sort an array with coordinates by their shortest distance to each other". _Please_ be clear on exactly what you want.

Comment: @PatrickQ I hope/think it's better now.